# Android TextView with image and dynamic value

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing apps in android. I did design for TextView in my apps see image 1[image]

```
This is my xml code

   <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/img"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:text="Recommend Outlet"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

I want TextView style like following image

[image]

The Value of 2 with Recommend Outlet is dynamically set from json Object.

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
tv.setText("Recommend Outlet " + cus_recommend);
tv.setTextSize(10);
```

How can I set Outlet Text Below Recommend Outlet..? Does anybody have solution ?

Comment: Why not use two text views and put the dynamic one underneath?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `android:singleLine="false"` attribute to your `TextView` XML as below...

```
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/img"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:text="Recommend Outlet"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:singleLine="false" />
```

and then add new line operator (`\n`) as below...

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
tv.setText("Recommend Outlet \n" + cus_recommend);
tv.setTextSize(10);
```

Comment: This is a good idea!  I personally would rather set them as two separate things - I just somehow think I have more control that way. I think the OP is using a linear layout though so yours is the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

Make the text two lines. If the first is stagnant then put the dynamic one underneath.  Don't forget to rename it your Activity.

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/img"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:text="Recommend Outlet:"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


<TextView
       android:id="@+id/json_data"
       android:layout_below="@id/tv" />
```